# Apply filters to a list view placed on a page as webpart based on loggeed in user, also how to export the current view to excel

Tags: list-view, export, xslt-list-view-web-part, client-side-rendering

Given below my scenario,

I have a list named **User Configuration** which stores user and country detail

```
User (People or group field)  |  Country (Dropdown choice field)
----------------------------------------------------------------
User A                        |  Hong Kong
User B                        |  China
User B                        |  Singapore
```

I have another list named **Transactions** with below schema

```
Title (Single line of text)   |  Country (Dropdown choice field)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Aaaaaa                        |  Hong Kong
Bbbbbb                        |  Hong Kong
Cccccc                        |  Singapore
Dddddd                        |  Singapore
Eeeeee                        |  Singapore
Ffffff                        |  China
Ggggggg                       |  China
```

I have added the AllItems list view as a listview webpart in a SharePoint page and also i have added a html button in the page content by placing a script editor webpart.

Now what i need is, When User A has logged in and viewing the page, the view should be like below, **User A belongs to Hong Kong, so he should be able to see only items of Hong Kong**

```
Title (Single line of text)   |  Country (Dropdown choice field)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Aaaaaa                        |  Hong Kong
Bbbbbb                        |  Hong Kong
```

This will be the view for User B, **User B belongs to China and Singapore, so he should be able to see only items of China and Singapore**

```
Title (Single line of text)   |  Country (Dropdown choice field)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Cccccc                        |  Singapore
Dddddd                        |  Singapore
Eeeeee                        |  Singapore
Ffffff                        |  China
Ggggggg                       |  China
```

Also, as i mentioned before, I have a html button in the page. By clicking that button the user should be able to export the current view in the page. Is there any option for that?

**Things I have tried and I dont want to do:**

1. I dont want to create seperate view for User A and User B and add as
   webpart in page and set Target audience for those webparts. This
   approach is not dynamic
2. I wont set item level pemission for each item so that by default user will not see other items he doesnt belong to.
3. I wont go for customization too, everything should be through JavaScript
4. For export to excel button, i dont want `owssvr.dll` approah as it will be static with a particular view. Eg. `<site url>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={<List GUID>}&View={<View GUID>}&CacheControl=1`

**Approach I need:**

1. I just wanted to know is there any way to achieve it through Client
   side rendering approach, so that the filter value set for the view should be dynamic
2. I wish the export to excel should also be dynamic
3. I got an idea like creating a complete list view webpart on page load using JavaScript. Is there any possibility for this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about the view, maybe map these lists with look-up fields somehow? There's a good article on the custom export to excel button: http://danssharepointblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-create-export-to-excel-button.html

Comment: How do you say with lookup field am not getting you? Also I have already tried the export to excel as said in the blog you shared. But that is not wanted as i have already said in my question, it will not be dynamic.

Comment: In Transactions list, your Country field can be a look-up to an item in User Configuration list and include User field as additional property. Then you can filter by that field in your view. And if the view will be dynamic, the export will be dynamic as well.

Comment: @GintasK don't think user fields can be added as additional properties in a lookup field.

Comment: @Submits oh, right... Calculated column then? workflow?

Comment: @GintasK You can't use user fields in your calculated column formula either. Don't we just love SharePoint? :) Workflow could be an option, but more effort.

Comment: @NagarajanMuthukumar would you be ok with the output view NOT being a list view webpart, rather just a plain html table?

Comment: @Submits Just displaying a HTML will not provide the look and feel of a list view webpart. I know this can be customized, but is there any other easy way. I hope it can be done by CSR, thats why i have posted this question.

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow, but it will require a workflow. Let me know if that's not an option for you. I can't think of any other way you can do this with the requirements that you've set.

Comment: If there is a solution with workflow lte me tr that also.

Comment: Any helps on this?

Comment: I got an idea like creating a complete list view webpart on page load using JavaScript. Is there any possibility for this?